# In React, how to map collection data object to an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have react component in which I am calling API and getting data collection. I have define an interface and I want to map incoming data from API to the interface that is define in the react but getting undefined. I know one option is to use map but I am trying to assign values to variable

```
result = [
   {id=1, name="kz", address="London", transactions: [{ id=1, amount=21}] },
   {id=1, name="abc", address="Manchester", transactions: [{ id=1, amount=21}] },
   {id=1, name="xyz", address="Edinburgh", transactions: [{ id=1, amount=21}] }
]
```

### Interface

```
export interface IMyData{
id :number,
name : string
address: string,
  transactions :[
      id: number,
      amount: number
  ]
}
```

Calling API and assigning data object

```
  const [eziData, setEziData] = useState<IMyData>();

  const result = await ....//getting api data

  setEziData(result);
```

getting eziData undefined when I console.log

Comment: are you calling const result = await. ... inside the function component immediately? or in the another event something like click event

Comment: there is another nested fuction where I am calling  const result = await immediately

Comment: `transactions: {id:number, amount: number}[]`

Comment: I think you want to change the type of your state from IMyData to IMyData[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setEziData` is the asynchronous method so you can't get the updated value of `eziData` immediately after `setEziData`.

```
setEziData(result);
console.log(eziData); // This will show the old `eziData ` value.
```

You should get the updated result in the useEffect with adding a `eziData` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(eziData);
}, [eziData]);
```

---

state type is also wrong.

```
  const [eziData, setEziData] = useState<IMyData[]>();
```

Comment: I have define const [eziData, setEziData] = useState<IMyData[]>(); and after assigning values I am trying to get length by  return (
        <div>
           {console.log("data legth", eziScheduleData.length)}     but getting error of length of undefined

Comment: what is eziScheduleData ? you mean, eziData ?

Comment: if I print inside the return (<div> {console.log("data", eziScheduleData)}.. It shows me correct result but cannot work out the length ... I need this value to apply condition with the map<....

Comment: that's because eziData is empty at the first. you need to set the initial value.
  const [eziData, setEziData] = useState<IMyData>([]);

Comment: many thanks it was really helpful, I have accepted your answer.